# How to disable JS in Python Selenium Chrome Driver , when driver is launched

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Can I disable java script, if my driver is launched? And later enable it.
Launch driver with disabled java script does not fit.